# How do I resize an image in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, image-resizing

I have an image that is 90px x 90px (it's a jpg file) and I can't figure out how to make it 60px by 60px in internet explorer. I looked at a few sites already which told me to use this css style:

```
.img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
```

but nothing happened. This is the css I'm using currently which works really well in fireforx and chrome:

```
.img {
    horiz-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px rgb(218, 218, 218) solid;
    background: #C4C4C4 no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened? No image or no resizing?

Comment: what's the purpose of `horiz-align`? never heard about it. Is it standard CSS?

Comment: You shouldn't _really_ resize images in the browser. Width and height should usually be defined inline within the html so that even if the image/css is not yet loaded the browser already implements a block with the right size for your image

Comment: no resizing happened. And here's more info on horiz-align: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: @RDoolabh but that specific property is not mentioned in the page and on SO it's usually better to avoid w3schools links as reference (see w3fools.com)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan didn't know that. Interesting

Comment: Finally I've found something about that property: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css/keywords.html (if anyone is interested)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your original code is you're specifying img as a class i.e `.img` rather than `img`

Here's 2 ways to do this. 1st with no css:

```
<img src="your-image.jpg" alt="" width="60" height="60" />
```

2nd with CSS:

```
<img src="your-image.jpg" alt="" class="image-resize" />
```

...

```
img.image-resize { 
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px; }
```

Comment: Or <img src="your-image.jpg" alt="" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" />.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `inherit` like:-

```
img {
  width: inherit;  /* This makes the next two lines work in IE8. */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;   
}
```

Comment: the width inherit didn't make any difference for me